# Error de configuración de dos bloques en Nginx para dos sitios de WordPress

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vps, ubuntu-server

Quiero hostear dos sitios en un mismo VPS, al instalar el certificado SSL con cloudflare me lanza el siguiente error:

> nginx emerg duplicate listen options for 443 in
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ejemplo1.com

**Bloque de configuración Sitio 1**

```
server {
    listen         80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
root /var/www/ejemplo1.com/public_html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name .ejemplo1.com;
client_max_body_size 0;

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ejemplo1.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ejemplo1.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_timeout 20m;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
if ($uri !~ "^/uploads/") {
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
}
location = /favicon.ico {
log_not_found off;
access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
log_not_found off;
access_log off;
allow all;
}

location ~* .(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
expires 1y;
log_not_found off;
}

# Enable Gzip compression.
gzip on;

# Disable Gzip on IE6.
gzip_disable "msie6";

# Allow proxies to cache both compressed and regular version of file.
# Avoids clients that don't support Gzip outputting gibberish.
gzip_vary on;

# Compress data, even when the client connects through a proxy.
gzip_proxied any;

# The level of compression to apply to files. A higher compression level increases
# CPU usage. Level 5 is a happy medium resulting in roughly 75% compression.
gzip_comp_level 5;

# Compress the following MIME types.
gzip_types
 application/atom+xml
 application/javascript
 application/json
 application/ld+json
 application/manifest+json
 application/rss+xml
 application/vnd.geo+json
 application/vnd.ms-fontobject
 application/x-font-ttf
 application/x-web-app-manifest+json
 application/xhtml+xml
 application/xml
 font/opentype
 image/bmp
 image/svg+xml
 image/x-icon
 text/cache-manifest
 text/css
 text/plain
 text/vcard
 text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
 text/vtt
 text/x-component
 text/x-cross-domain-policy;
}
```

En el caso del Bloque del Sitio 2 es practicamente el mismo lo único que cambia es el nombre del dominio y la ruta de la carpeta donde estarán alojados los archivos. En este caso no se si se debe omitir el puerto 443 para este segundo archivo de configuración

**Bloque de configuración Sitio 2**

```
server {
    listen         80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
root /var/www/ejemplo2.com/public_html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name .ejemplo2.com;
client_max_body_size 0;

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/ejemplo2.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/ejemplo2.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_timeout 20m;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
if ($uri !~ "^/uploads/") {
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
}
location = /favicon.ico {
log_not_found off;
access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
log_not_found off;
access_log off;
allow all;
}

location ~* .(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
expires 1y;
log_not_found off;
}

# Enable Gzip compression.
gzip on;

# Disable Gzip on IE6.
gzip_disable "msie6";

# Allow proxies to cache both compressed and regular version of file.
# Avoids clients that don't support Gzip outputting gibberish.
gzip_vary on;

# Compress data, even when the client connects through a proxy.
gzip_proxied any;

# The level of compression to apply to files. A higher compression level increases
# CPU usage. Level 5 is a happy medium resulting in roughly 75% compression.
gzip_comp_level 5;

# Compress the following MIME types.
gzip_types
 application/atom+xml
 application/javascript
 application/json
 application/ld+json
 application/manifest+json
 application/rss+xml
 application/vnd.geo+json
 application/vnd.ms-fontobject
 application/x-font-ttf
 application/x-web-app-manifest+json
 application/xhtml+xml
 application/xml
 font/opentype
 image/bmp
 image/svg+xml
 image/x-icon
 text/cache-manifest
 text/css
 text/plain
 text/vcard
 text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
 text/vtt
 text/x-component
 text/x-cross-domain-policy;
}
```

Que debo hacer para que al ejecutar no me lance el error.

**sudo nginx -t**

La documentación la obtuve de esta página

[Install WordPress with Ubuntu 18.04, NGINX, MariaDB and PHP 7.4](https://gulshankumar.net/install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que el primer bloque server de los archivos de configuración es para forzar el trafico por 443 HTTPS, pero los dos están escuchando al mismo tiempo, es verdad que luego cambia cuando se pasa a 443, no se si tendrá que ver pero podrías agregar una directiva como "server_name" para cada uno de los bloques de servidor.

Ejemplo:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    ejemplo2.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

De esta manera también te evitas redirecciones innecesarias con URLs que no existen.